# importing words from text

Tags: java, swing, text, hashset

I apologize since I'm always asking n00b questions but I could really use the help. Anyways I'm trying to import words of only a certain length from the dictionary into the variable words which is a hash set. When I run my program and try to print my words aka the hashset of strings. I get nothing in the console and the program does not stop running. How can I fix this? P.S. Also I know part of the JOptionPane code got cut enough, but it's error free and you get the point. Thanks!
Alex

```
 public void inputWords()
  {
      try
       {
        frame = new JFrame("Hangman");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("dictionary.txt"));
        wordLength = Integer.parseInt(  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,                                                                        
        String importedWords = input.nextLine();
        while(stillHasWords==true)
        {   
            if(importedWords.length()==wordLength)
            {   
                words.add(importedWords);
            }

            else
            {

            }

        }   

    }   

    catch(FileNotFoundException f)
    {
        System.out.println("File does not exist.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    catch(NoSuchElementException q)
    {
        stillHasWords=false;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
    EvilHangman j = new EvilHangman();
    System.out.println(stillHasWords);
    j.inputWords();
    System.out.println(words + " ");

        }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding:

```
    while(stillHasWords==true)
    {   
        if(importedWords.length()==wordLength)
        {   
            words.add(importedWords);
        }

        else
        {

        }

    }
```

I'm not sure what words.add(importedWords) does, but most important to the problem you're experiencing,

Question: Where do you change stillHasWords inside of your loop?
Answer: You don't, and so the loop will never end.

I suggest that first you fix this while loop

As an aside, it's better to avoid using == true in a while loop and instead simply test the boolean:

```
while (stillHasWords) {
  // add a word
  // change stillHasWords to false if we've run out of words
}
```

---

**Edit**
You state:

> Still has words changes in the catch(NoSuchElementException q)

There is no catch block posted **inside of the while loop**, and so I submit that still the stillHasWords value cannot change inside of the while loop *based on code you've posted so far*. If you have more pertinent code, then you'll of course want to show it, else we're reduced to guessing what *might* be wrong with code not shown. Best to post an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org)

Comment: Still has words changes in the catch(NoSuchElementException q)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm sorry "I've reduced you to guessing what might be". I'll post better questions next time